# Bamboo Atlassian: How to share a variable between stages

Tags: bamboo, artifacts

I am relatively new to **Bamboo**. I have a question regarding stages implementation with shared variable. I have two stages:

Stage 1:
    Set variable "Sample_build_number"

Stage 2: 
    Use variable "Sample_build_number"

Any help with this is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write your variables to a simple property file in Stage 1, and share the property file as an artifact.

```
Sample_build_number=myvalue
```

In your Stage 2 job use the [Inject Bamboo variables](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/configuring-a-variables-task-687213475.html) task to read the property file.

Your variable is available in later job steps as `${bamboo.inject.Sample_build_number}`

Note this uses the [Bamboo Inject Variables Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.bamboo-variable-inject-plugin/server/overview) that is bundled in versions 5.7 and later. If you have an earlier version of Bamboo your administrator will need to download and install the plugin.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to get it working with your solution.
I am also able to get the variable in the second stage just by marking artifact as share and then simply cat the content of the artifact on later stage.

Comment: @Steffen Opel "+1" can i use the variable during deployment which has been created during build.